# EF CORE API not adding access-control-allow-origin response header ONLY in html2canvas

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, html2canvas

My problem is that when html2canvas try to render one image, it fails telling me that there is a problem with cors policy. I checked the request and i saw that  access-control-allow-origin is not present on the response headers.

I added this code on my Startap.cs and in the Configure() method on my api:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
                return next.Invoke();
            });
```

The code abouve adds Access-Control-Allow-Origin to ALL response headers, except for when HTML2canvas tries to get the image.

Remenber, only when html2cavas tries to get the image from the api, that i have this problem with cors.

Everything else is working fine.

Can anyone help?

Here is frontend code:

```
html2canvas(data, {logging: true, allowTaint: false, useCORS: true }).then(canvas => {
        // var imgWidth = 220;
        // var pageHeight = 320;
        var imgWidth = 280; // valor anterior: 280
        var pageHeight = 1000; //valor anterior: 1000
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        //var imgHeight = 2000;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;
        var widthLeft = imgWidth;

        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        let pdf = new jspdf('landscape', 'mm', 'a4', true); // A4 size page of PDF
        var position = 0;
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');

        pdf.save('PadronTecnico.pdf'); // Generated PDF
        this.blockUI.stop();

        this.showScrolls = true;
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the response headers on Configure() method and it worked perfectly!

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Resources")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources"),
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                }
            });
```